# Bash command not found on macos

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-amplify

I am unable to run certain (macos) terminal commands after switching back to bash from temporarily using zsh. One of the commands is 'amplify publish' which returns the following error:

**bash: amplify: command not found**

I have installed the amplify cli globally using: *npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli*

**echo $PATH returns /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin**

and the contents of my .bashrc file is as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

export EDITOR="code --wait"
```

Amplify is not the only command that is suddenly missing, but this is the most pressing.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Run `npm root -g` to see where global packages are installed.

Comment: Or check your `zsh` configuration to see which directory it added to `PATH` that your `bash` configuration does not.

Comment: @chepner that command returns: /Users/john/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules. also i couldnt get amplify to work on zsh either, which is why i reverted back to using bash.

Comment: Does `/Users/john/.npm-packages/bin` exist?

Comment: @chepner it does exist!

Comment: @chepner thanks so much! appending that path to the current PATH variable solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

appending that path to the globally installed npm package folder to the current PATH variable solved my issue!